# Call a function from inside of a bash script in terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have written a function called

```
random_init()
```

It takes two parameters username and password.Is there a way to call it from the terminal like this.

```
$ random init username password
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just call the function as you wrote in the question: `random_init "username" "password"`

Comment: You could call the containing bash script, add the parameters as args, and in the script pass the args to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `source` the script in which your function is defined:

```
. my_script.sh 
# or (bash)
source my_script.sh
```

Then call your function:

```
random_init 'username' 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the function in your `.bashrc file` , then you can call like this

```
random_init 'username' 'password'
```